# How to interprete the Pandas Index class documentation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Please help me read and use the great Pandas documentation better.

E.g.[pandas.Index.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.contains.html) and the [overview of attributes and methods for the Pandas Index class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html#pandas.Index).

In this case, I want to check if a key is in the index before applying

```
dataframe.loc['key',['column']]) # first check if key is in index to avoid KeyError: 'the label [key] is not in the [index]'
```

I want to use the method contains(key) ("return a boolean if this key is IN the index").

So I incorrectly tried dataframe.Index.contains. But it should be index and not  Index. So why is it written with a capital in the documentation?

Also, it should be with .str in between index and contains:

```
dataframe.index.str.contains('key')) # not dataframe.Index.contains
```

It is my fault, but how should I know this from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether a key is in index then use `.isin` i.e ("return a boolean array if this key is IN the index")

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],['b','c'],['c','z'],['d','b']])

   0  1
0  a  b
1  b  c
2  c  z
3  d  b

df.index.isin([1,2])
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

For a scalar use `in` i.e. `k in df.index` where k is any number or scalar

Eg:

```
2 in df.index
True 

df.index.isin([2])
array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Or `k in df.index` for one value.

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know about k in df.index, that is great!  I guess that is more generic and therefore not on the Index doc page. I knew about index.isin([list]) and used that with a scalar by checking if the sum is 0 or 1 (sum(dataframe.index.str.contains('key')). FYI I also did dataframe['indexCopy'] = dataframe.index with dataframe['indexCopy'].get('key ', False) (since .get only works on series but not on 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'). So I have the solution and my question is also how to get that myself from reading the docs. But maybe this is also just experience :)

Comment: Not every case is covered in Documentation. Better is to search Stack Overflow or Google. If you keep experimenting you will know understand better.